# Does adding a user without a password to a Docker container pose a security issue?

Tags: docker, dockerfile

Does adding a user without a password to a Docker container pose a security issue?  I added the following lines to the php Dockerfile to fix the permission issue of files:

```
RUN addgroup -g ${gid} --system laravel
RUN adduser -G laravel --system -D -s /bin/sh -u ${uid} laravel
RUN sed -i "s/user = www-data/user = laravel/g" /usr/local/etc/php-fpm.d/www.conf
RUN sed -i "s/group = www-data/group = laravel/g" /usr/local/etc/php-fpm.d/www.conf
```

It creates a user with the given uid and gid, however, no password is set for the user. I would like to know if such a thing may pose a security issue to the container.

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The setup you show is extremely routine and I wouldn't worry about it.

At a Docker-container level, the container *only* runs the main process identified by the `ENTRYPOINT` and `CMD` directives, as overridden by runtime.  It doesn't run a login service, **getty**(8), or anything else that might accept or verify a password.  The `docker run -u` option will let the operator pick an arbitrary user to use, and Docker won't do any checking on whether that user is "allowed" (or, if its a numeric user ID, if it's even listed in `/etc/passwd`).

At a Unix level, an account can have a disabled password.  The [**adduser**(8)](https://linux.die.net/man/8/adduser) documentation for the `-p, --password` option notes

> The default is to disable the password.

so *not* setting a password is a little more secure.

The Stack Overflow questions that I see that do try to use **passwd**(1) have some major security issues in themselves.  The password is almost always very guessable (I frequently see `password`, without even a `0`).  It's written down in plain text in the Dockerfile, so it can be found in source control.  It's also recorded in the image metadata, so `docker history` also shows it to anyone who has the image.

I might remove the `-u` (explicitly set uid) and `-s` (shell) options.  When you use this user later on, do not **chown**(1) every file in your image to that user, only a specific directory of files that actually need to be written.  But if you do that, setting up a non-root user this way is good practice.

Comment: Very comprehensive and well-detailed answer. thank you very much.